# Normalisation with 0/NULL values or can it be designed better?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

I am in the process of planning my DB in MySQL for the following scenario -

I am trying to build a play by play system such as NBA where, events such as

```
 Play event[id, play_type_id, play_outcome_id, points] 

  Substitution event[id, player1_in_id, player2_out_id]  

  Foul event[id, foul_type_id, player_id]
```

In the main play_by_play scorecard a particular event should be linked with a particular time and match

```
Play_by_Play[id, match_id, time_id, play_event_id, substitution_event_id, foul_event_id]
```

However assuming at one particular minute only one of the three events takes place- only one event record out of three will have id, and others will be either 0 or NULL. I am left with the question is this good Normalisation for this design or is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: For play_by_play scorecard you will need to Join tables and get the required Data. It should be a view not a table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, You're right, I could be able to join the tables. However my problem is if I have to insert a Play by Play record it looks like this [1,10,5,0,1,0] means only one of the events among gets a record at particular time and I am forced to enter 0's  for other events. Can you please suggest on how I can make this design better ?

Comment: You shouldn't have a table called play by play, sorry I dont understand how a basketball game works but you should split your tables in a way that one insert only handles one type of event, and only affects the table that the event is related to, if you have a table which doesnt match the business model then it is not the right schema.

Comment: If the goal is to track players, then I would argue that a substitution is two events -- player1 removed & player2 added.

Comment: You have different types/kinds of events. Google stackoverflow.com database/sql subtypes for idioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is only one answer and it is highly dependent on how you use your data.

**One way** is to have `Play_by_Play` table include a single reference to an event and thus avoiding the overhead of NULLs and 0s.

```
Play_by_Play[id, match_id, time_id, event_id]
```

You can define a generic event

```
Event_type [event_type_id, type_name]
Generic_Event[event_id, event_type_id]
```

and all the other event types can be 1:1 extensions for this generic event type:

```
Play event[id, event_id, play_type_id, play_outcome_id, points] 
Substitution event[id, event_id, player1_in_id, player2_out_id]  
Foul event[id, event_id, foul_type_id, player_id]
```

This design favors normalization and allows to quickly select information about the events regardless of their type (your design requires multiple joins for this).

However, aggregating information will require more joins (to the tables actually holding relevant data for events) and also `Generic_Event` might grow very much with potential effects upon performance.

**Your way** favors faster aggregation of information, as you can query only `Play_by_Play` table. E.g.: get number of substitutions and number of fouls within a time frame.

It might also more space and query execution efficient, as you use less `JOIN`s and do not have a big event table.

It is unclear what is your actual database engine (you tagged both MySql and SQL Server), but for SQL Server there is a feature that helps you optimize space for tables with lots of NULL values: [sparse columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604(v=sql.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to track events, then focus on one row per event in a single table.

Blend `play_type` and `foul_type` into a single `type`, with `substitution as another`type`.

Consider splitting "substitution" into two events:  Player being removed and player being added.  This eliminates the extra player column that exists just for this event.  (But it complicates things if you want to call it a single event.)

There may need to be a small number of `NULLable` columns.